# Calculate expectation of a function with two dependent random variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, covariance, conditional-expectation, independence

Hi Cross Validated community,

My question has to do regarding expectation of a multiplication of two random variables that are dependent.

Assume there are two random variables, one discrete: $G \in \{0,1\}$ and one continuous: $D \in (0, 1000)$, the two variables are dependent $G \rightarrow D$. The payoff function $F$ is then defined as follows:

$$
F(g, d) = \begin{cases}
    1.5 \cdot d & \text{if } g = 1 \\
    -10 & \text{if } g = 0
\end{cases}
$$

How can one calculate the expectation
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\mathop{\E}_{P(G,D)}[F(g,d)]$$

given that the joint probability $P(G,D)$ is not known and difficult to model. Currently I have $E[D]$ out of an estimator and $P(G)$ out of a classifier.

If I assume **independence** between $G$ and $D$, the expression should be straightforward:

$$
\E[F(g,d)] = P(G=0)\cdot (-10) + P(G=1) \cdot \E[D] \cdot 1.5
$$

**Now the question is how to do this for G and D being dependent.** What would be the best way to go about correctly expressing and calculating this expectation? Some of the ideas are:

1. Perhaps I may somehow use the following trick by adding covariance somehow, (It is however unclear to me how can I correctly add this into the expectation formula):

$$
\E[GD] = \E[G] \cdot \E[D]+cov[G,D]
$$

2. Or perhaps I will have to model $P(D|G)$ to calculate the expectation?

Thank you for your help and ideas. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume **dependence**, the expression is given by:

$$\mathbb E[F(g,d)] = P(G=0)\cdot (-10) + P(G=1) \cdot \mathbb E[D|G=1] \cdot 1.5$$

Can you estimate $\mathbb E[D|G=1]$ ?

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer, you simplified the problem quite well for me. Yes, perhaps I can estimate E[D|G=1] from data as a sample mean out of best fit distribution on data where G=1?( In R perhaps using package: gamlss and fitDist method). The only thing that remains now is how to best estimate the E[D|G=1], Now If I was unable to estimate this correctly from data, would there be another way to solve this? Maybe estimate Cov[G,D] and plug it using the formula I mentioned?

Comment: If you prefer you can go with covariance formula. What you write is correct, and is indeed the definition of covariance. How many $(g,d)$ points do you have? Don't you think estimating $\mathbb E[D|G=1]$  is easier than estimating the covariance? Just average the $d$ of the $G=1$ data ;-)

Comment: Thank you, that is a good point : ). The r.v. D is actually some form of ''price'' and hence not normally distributed, so it may be that a sample mean is not informative enough in this case, (additionally there is some temporality in D, that D1 depends on D0. Am I able to use sample mean in this case?. 

One more question, I have advanced regressor that estimates E[D] and takes into account temporality, is there a way to use this estimate, perhaps just shift it somehow to obtain E[D|G=1] ? 

Thanks so much : )

Comment: The current model does not take into account a time factor. As is, the expression of the answer gives you your expected value. Also note that the sample average is _always_ an unbiased estimator of the expected value (for example, see this [link](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/mean-estimation#hid9))

Comment: Thanks, u have answered my question perfectly. Does time break this model? I mean if D is time dependent i.e. D2 is dependent on D1, D0 etc? Thanks for answer.

Comment: By what you say, time dependence must be present in your model of D. If $D_n$ only depends on $D_{n-1}$, it is a first-order [Markov chain](https://brilliant.org/wiki/markov-chains/); if it depends on a finite number $n$ of past states, it is an $n^{th}$-order Markov chain. I have no idea what is the usual procedure to model prices. It is probably better to talk with someone on the field, or ask a new question.